# Did not receive 'Nice Question' badge

Tags: support, badges

I didn't receive 2 'Nice Question' badges for the following questions.

[File chooser dialog not closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838089/file-chooser-dialog-not-closing)
[The form:form tag declares that it accepts dynamic attributes but does not implement the required interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648357/the-formform-tag-declares-that-it-accepts-dynamic-attributes-but-does-not-imple)

Is this badge nearly the same as a 'Nice Answer' badge? In that it takes some time to receive the badge due to some reason.

Can anyone please explain?

Comment: Umm, you need a score of 10, meaning 10 more up- than downvotes, for the badge.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It does look confusing at first, but the score of 10 refers to the net amount of upvotes you receive for your question (Or answer in the case of Nice Answer). It doesn't refer to the amount of rep that you earn from it. Otherwise we'd all have nice answers when we simply get one upvote.

Comment: oh so you mean 50 net reputations? Now I understand.

Comment: @Raghul: no, not 50 net reputation. You can have 12 upvotes and 5 downvotes on a question, then you'd have 50 net rep from that question, but the net *score* of that question would be 7. Not enough for a Nice Question badge.

Answer (score 8):

Reputation is different from question score. With 2 upvotes on each question you gained 10 reputation.

However, the question does not have a score of 10. You need 10 upvotes (and no downvotes) in order to get a score of 10. Or 12 upvotes and 2 downvotes etc.