# Change the name of the badges

Tags: feature-request

I see a lot of questions about a 'Nice Question' badge and 'Nice Answer' badge about their being not awarded one of the 2 mentioned badges.
I too misunderstood the badge definition given and asked [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159066/did-not-receive-nice-question-badge).

Now why shan't one of the moderators change the definition of 'Nice Question' to -
"Question with net up-votes of 10 or more" or something of that kind for the 6 similar badges (Nice Question, Nice Answer, Good Question, Good Answer, Great Question & Great Answer) with 6 6 similar definitions?
The score mentioned in the definition easily confuses one with reputation score.

This may be a bad suggestion but thought it could be considered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well once you understand how one works, you understand them all (6).

There is a difference between Question/Answer `Score` and Account `Reputation` and both are refered too differently in the badges section.

- A score badge : `Answer score of 25 or more`.
- A reputation badge : `Active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation`.

I don't think any current badges need their names changed and especially not for a name that states the definition of "How to get the badge".